# Can someone look over this for me, I can't figure out how to fix it: TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

I'm fairly sure what and where are the problems, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

The code thus far:

```
def parseFasta(fasta):
 sequence = ""
 fasta = open("rosalind_lcsm.fasta", "r")
 for line in fasta:
      if ">" in line:
           pass
      else:
           sequence += line.strip()
 return sequence.split()

def hid_motif(data):
  substrs = lambda x: {x[i:i+j] for i in range(len(x)) for j in range(len(x) - i + 1)}
  s = (substrs(data[0]))
  for val in data[1:]:
    s.intersection_update(substrs(val))
  return max(s, key=len)

print hid_motif(parseFasta)
```

The error:

```
File "hmotif.py", line 18, in <module>
print hid_motif(parseFasta)
  File "hmotif.py", line 13, in hid_motif
s = (substrs(data[0]))
```

Comment: `parseFasta` is a function, not a `data` `list`.  Try: `hid_motif(parseFasta())` based on what you have defined.  Note you have to call `parseFasta` as a function and pass that output to `hid_motif`.

Comment: Last line: `print hid_motif(parseFasta)` should be `print hid_motif(parseFasta())`. Notice I added parentheses at the end because you telling the compiler to perform a function. When you just do `parseFasta`, you pass in (god knows how) a function itself.....don't try to figure out the last part please, it can be pretty confusing.

Comment: Thanks! Now on to the memory error...

Answer (score 0):

`data` is the function `parseFasta`, just as you passed in. And you can't use the `[]` notation with a function.

Perhaps you meant to *call* the `parseFasta` function, which would pass in the result, rather than the function itself. But you'll need an argument.

Answer (score 0):

As kindall mentioned

since you have declared the function

```
def parseFasta(fasta):
   ...
```

Which needs an input argument

You need to type:

```
print hid_motif(parseFasta(input_argument))
```

Where input_argument is the required input to your `parseFasta(Fasta)` function
ie. Fasta will copy the value/s of `input_argument`

Comment: since the initial imput argument is fasta then would it be: